Find the minimum of $|PA|+\frac{|AB|}{2}$
Let $C$ be the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ and let $A$ be a point on $C$. And let $B$ be a point on the line $x-2y-8=0$. If $P(0,1)$, how to find the minimum of $|PA|+\frac{|AB|}{2}$?
I believe there must be some tricky geometric way to solve this question. But I have no idea yet. Any hints?


Probably have to bash it with coordinates. Also, did you mean that AB is perpendicular to the line?

@BenjaminWang No, the points A and B are free.

Do you mean $(|PA|+|PB|)/2?$

Des $P$ have to be in the fourth quadrant? I don't see any reason to expect this to have a good closed form. It will have a closed form, but it won't be nice.

@ThomasAndrews No, I mean $|PA|+\frac{|AB|}{2}$.

Clearly if searching for minimum $AB$ must be perpendicular to given line.

Let $P'(0,4)$, then we can easily verify that for any point $A$ on the circle, we have $|P'A|=2|PA|$. Hence
$$
|PA|+\frac{|AB|}{2} = \frac{1}{2}(|P'A|+|AB|).
$$
While $|P'A|+|AB| \geq |PD|$, where $D$ is the projection of $P$ onto the line $x-2y-8=0$.
By direct computation, $|P'D| = \frac{|0-2\times 4-8|}{\sqrt{5}} = \frac{16}{\sqrt5}$. So
$$
\biggl(|PA|+\frac{|AB|}{2}\biggr)_{\min} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{16}{\sqrt5} = \frac{8}{\sqrt5}.
$$


Appollonius circle! Nice :)

It took me several hours to think of using the Appollonius circle! :-)

@Stephen. Great answer! I guess the question was designed so that $P'D$ intersects the circle.
